# UISearchBar not working or disabled after adding Tab Bar or Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I implemented a search bar to filter the result. It was working perfectly but then when I embedded this View Controller with a Navigation Controller, which is also associated with a Tab Bar Controller, the search bar did not respond when I clicked it. It also looks like it was disabled.

Here's how it looks
[image]

My storyboards

[image]

My code for the feed view controller:

```
import UIKit
import AlamofireImage


class RestaurantsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        
    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    // Initiliazers
    var restaurantsArray: [Restaurant] = []
    
    // Add Search Bar Outlet + Variable for filtered Results
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var filteredRestaurants: [Restaurant] = []
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Table View
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        // Search Bar delegate
        searchBar.delegate = self
        definesPresentationContext = true
        
        // Get Data from API
        getAPIData()

    }
    
    
    // Update API results + restaurantsArray Variable + filteredRestaurants
    func getAPIData() {
        API.getRestaurants() { (restaurants) in
            guard let restaurants = restaurants else {
                return
            }
            self.restaurantsArray = restaurants
            self.filteredRestaurants = restaurants
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tableView.rowHeight = 150
        }
    }
}

// ––––– TableView Functionality –––––
extension RestaurantsViewController {
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredRestaurants.count
    }
    
    // Configure cell to use [Movie] array instead of [[String:Any]] and Filtered Array
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Create Restaurant Cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RestaurantCell") as! RestaurantCell
        
        // Set cell's restaurant
        cell.r = filteredRestaurants[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    // Send restaurant object to DetailViewController
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            let r = filteredRestaurants[indexPath.row]
            let detailViewController = segue.destination as! RestaurantDetailViewController
            detailViewController.r = r
        }
        
    }
    
}


// Add protocol + Functionality for Searching
// UISearchResultsUpdating informs the class of text changes
// happening in the UISearchBar
extension RestaurantsViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    // Search bar functionality
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText != "" {
            filteredRestaurants = restaurantsArray.filter { (r: Restaurant) -> Bool in
              return r.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            }
        }
        else {
            filteredRestaurants = restaurantsArray
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    
    // Show Cancel button when typing
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
       self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }
       
    // Logic for searchBar cancel button
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
       searchBar.showsCancelButton = false // remove cancel button
       searchBar.text = "" // reset search text
       searchBar.resignFirstResponder() // remove keyboard
       filteredRestaurants = restaurantsArray // reset results to display
       tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I did try putting definesPresentationContext in viewDidLoad() but it didn't make any difference for me. I think it's because either the tab bar controller or navigation controller that somehow "disabled" the search bar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This may help as you just ignore to input your view to `navigationItem`, which
can accept the event.

```
self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar = searchBar
```